# How to append repetitive index values to columns using python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I have many repetitive index values in certain sequence.
I want to fetch the 1st value of my index cell 'ID' and when ever that value repeats, then append that set of values to next column. Here my Index values repeat 4 times, so output will have 4 columns labeled from i=1,2,3,4...till N for N no. of repeat index sets.

The starting value of index cell will differ for other data sets, but the values will repeat in same sequence.

Sample Dataset: df

```
ID,1
7,0.060896109
10,0.384263675
27,0.780060081
43,0.583200572
57,0.139564176
73,0.595220898
91,0.828783841
7,0.39920022
10,0.157306146
27,0.29750421
43,0.742234942
57,0.971849921
73,0.346905033
91,0.996723279
7,0.192197827
10,0.922323942
27,0.033304593
43,0.462253505
57,0.282632609
73,0.553047118
91,0.07678817
7,0.428707324
10,0.250935035
27,0.529861617
43,0.982468147
57,0.473807591
73,0.340980584
91,0.436675534
```

[image: in]

Expected Output Sample:

```
ID,1,2,3,4
7,0.060896109,0.39920022,0.192197827,0.428707324
10,0.384263675,0.157306146,0.922323942,0.250935035
27,0.780060081,0.29750421,0.033304593,0.529861617
43,0.583200572,0.742234942,0.462253505,0.982468147
57,0.139564176,0.971849921,0.282632609,0.473807591
73,0.595220898,0.346905033,0.553047118,0.340980584
91,0.828783841,0.996723279,0.07678817,0.436675534
```

[image: out]

Comment: First `ID` is index?

Comment: @jezrael - yes.1st id will be the index. 7 in this case, maybe some other value in another dataset, but the format will be the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with helper column created by compare by first column with cumulative `sum`:

```
df = df.assign(g=np.cumsum(df.index == df.index[0])).pivot(columns='g',values='1')
print (df)
g          1         2         3         4
ID                                        
7   0.060896  0.399200  0.192198  0.428707
10  0.384264  0.157306  0.922324  0.250935
27  0.780060  0.297504  0.033305  0.529862
43  0.583201  0.742235  0.462254  0.982468
57  0.139564  0.971850  0.282633  0.473808
73  0.595221  0.346905  0.553047  0.340981
91  0.828784  0.996723  0.076788  0.436676
```

Comment: for my full dataset, the index values are rearranging in the final output, all values starting with 1,10,100,110, etc are shown initially, then the 2,21,203,..then the 3's...and so on ..

Comment: @Axay - Then use `df.assign(g=np.cumsum(df.index == df.index[0])).pivot(columns='g',values='1').reindex(df.index.unique())`

Comment: Or before my solution `df.index = df.index.astype(int)` or `df = df.rename(int)`

Comment: ```df.assign(g=np.cumsum(df.index == df.index[0])).pivot(columns='g',values='1').reindex(df.index.unique())``` This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) with a little extra work on the columns:

```
pd.pivot_table(data=df, index='ID', columns=df.groupby('ID').cumcount(), values='1')

       0         1         2         3
ID                                        
7   0.060896  0.399200  0.192198  0.428707
10  0.384264  0.157306  0.922324  0.250935
27  0.780060  0.297504  0.033305  0.529862
43  0.583201  0.742235  0.462254  0.982468
57  0.139564  0.971850  0.282633  0.473808
73  0.595221  0.346905  0.553047  0.340981
91  0.828784  0.996723  0.076788  0.436676
```